# Making a 2D very simple running game with jumps. Same class?

Tags: java, image, class, jpanel, 2d

Hey I'm making a very simple Running Jumping game for my Java 1 class. The character is gonna run and jump over oncoming rocks. Should the rock and the running Boy be in the same class or separate?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
public class Boy extends JPanel {

JLabel Boy1;
ImageIcon Boy;

public Boy () {
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground (Color.white);


    Boy = new ImageIcon ("/Users/a/Documents/workspace/JumpyBoy/src/Boy.png");
    Boy1 = new JLabel (Boy, SwingConstants.CENTER);

    Boy1.setBounds(80, 300, 130, 500);

    add (Boy1);
}

}
```

Comment: since they rock and boy are two different entities, there should be two classes representing each one.

Comment: It would be easier to manage if they were different classes, this way you could manage the individual properties, create new instances easily and make changes which would affect the entire program

Comment: make different classes as there may be posibilites of adding addition member to `boy` that are not required by `rock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@niiraj874u is correct.  You want 2 classes.  One for the boy and one for the rock.

Generally speaking, different nouns should become different classes.

Each noun, a boy and a rock in this case, will have different actions (functions) to perform:  the boy will jump, the rock will roll (I guess).  And these functions should be encapsulated into the separate classes depending on which object does which action.